# How to set right corner design with alternate row color or image using CSS3 using Data Attribute value

Tags: html, css

i am having a scenario that i would place multiple section tags under a wrapper and each section tag will have data-corner as a data attribute, where i need to create corner right design with background transparent using CSS3. i have two scenario,

1. i am using alternate row color using css nth-child(odd) / (even) setting white color to odd and grey color to even.
2. in the same section some of the placeholders can have background image also. so i need to set transparent corner design to all section placed under the page. so please let me know how to achieve this using CSS3. NO jquery please.

View it on [Code pen](http://codepen.io/mbalaraman/pen/JdxVQb)

**CSS code**

```
.main-wrap > section:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.main-wrap > section:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.main-wrap > section {
    height: 100px;
    position-relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 50px 20px 20px
}

section:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
}

section:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
}

section[data-background="image"] {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="main-wrap">
    <section data-background="image" style='background-image:url("http://i1.wp.com/static.web-backgrounds.net/uploads/2012/08/City_Landscape_Background.jpg")'>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex doloremque possimus, facilis libero cumque temporibus, aliquid quaerat voluptas adipisci perspiciatis officia dolores excepturi voluptatem modi iure officiis, dicta ullam beatae.</div>

    </section>
    <section>
    <div>Quis dolorem recusandae id. Veniam dolorum a nemo est ducimus sed laboriosam unde laudantium aspernatur accusamus officia ab fugiat dicta maxime inventore, excepturi eaque, velit iste quaerat? Nobis, inventore, hic.</div>
    </section>
    <section>
     <div>Quis dolorem recusandae id. Veniam dolorum a nemo est ducimus sed laboriosam unde laudantium aspernatur accusamus officia ab fugiat dicta maxime inventore, excepturi eaque, velit iste quaerat? Nobis, inventore, hic.</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Sample Mockup design:** 
[image: Sample Mockup design]

Comment: Can you share any example of what have you tried?

Comment: It's too much of writing, and even if I try to imagine, I may be slightly wrong, would you mind providing some visualizations ? a sketch ?anything that can show your intended design ?

Comment: please find the below url: http://www.coroflot.com/bmanojbabu/test and this the sample mockup which i need achieve it

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to that specific design problem. It is a variation on css used [here](http://scottpdawson.com/development/three-methods-for-creating-beveled-corners-css-css3-or-jquery/).

```css
/* bevel size, left offset and color settings next 3 lines */ 
.bvc {
    width: 600px; /* width of overall box, variable or fixed */ 
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bolder;
}
.nomarg {
    margin-top:0px !important;
}

.trwhite { border-right-color: white !important; }
.trtrans { border-right-color: #EEE !important; }
.trred { border-right-color: red !important; }
.trgray { border-right-color: gray !important; }

.red, .red > div {
    background:red;
    background-color:red;
}
.red > div {
    border-color:red;
}
.white, .white > div {
    background:white;
    background-color:white;
}
.white > div {
    border-color:white;
}
.gray, .gray > div {
    background:gray;
    background-color:gray;
}
.gray > div {
    border-color:gray;
}
.black, .black > div {
    background:black ;
    background-color:black ;
    color:white;
}
.black > div {
    border-color:black;
}

.bevel, .content { border-width: 15px }
.bevel, .content { border-color: #efefef; border-style:solid; }
.tr, .bevel { 
    height: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    border-right-color: transparent; 
    border-top: 0; 
}

.content {
    background: #efefef no-repeat;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
}

body {
    margin: 20px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:18px;
    background:#EEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="bvc white nomarg">
    <div class="bevel tr trtrans"></div>
    <div class="content">Section 1</div>
</div>

<div class="bvc red ">
    <div class="bevel tr trwhite"></div>
    <div class="content">Section 2</div>
</div>

<div class="white bvc">
    <div class="bevel tr trred"></div>
    <div class="content">Section 3</div>
</div>

<div class="gray bvc">
    <div class="bevel tr trwhite"></div>
    <div class="content">Section 4</div>
</div>

<div class="white bvc">
    <div class="bevel tr trgray"></div>
    <div class="content">Section 5</div>
</div>

<div class="black bvc">
    <div class="bevel tr trwhite"></div>
    <div class="content">I need this design</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, really appreciate your effort. only the concern was i can't hard code the Row color, it will be based on Odd / Even as i mentioned in the design, some time there is background image will be used to display. using these constrains i need achieve the design. any idea how to handle this.

Comment: I'll look into it, read over that, sorry. Won't be for today probably though.